# A pair versus "suited" overcards

Tags: odds

Apparently when a pair goes against over cards it's known as a race because the odds are roughly even. What if the over-cards are suited? On average, how does that affect the odds?

Comment: approx. `2%` more chance for the suited overcards, still a race

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a reasonable improvement for the overcards when they are suited.  In the example of AK versus pocket tens, you improve from about 42.5% chance of winning to about 45.9% chance. AK does a little better against 99 than against tens, because the 10 blocks the possible straight.

Here are some examples from pokerstove.  First, unsuited AK against pocket tens, where the 10s are not blocking the suits of the AK:

```
        equity  win     tie     pots won  pots tied 
Hand 0: 42.724% 42.57%  00.16%  728909    2661.00   { AdKs }
Hand 1: 57.276% 57.12%  00.16%  978073    2661.00   { TcTh }
```

The best case for the overcards is for the player with the tens to not have the 10 of the same suit. Here is the suited AK against tens where the suit of the AKs is not also in the tens:

```
        equity  win     tie     pots won  pots tied 
Hand 0: 46.106% 45.92%  00.18%  786350    3127.00   { AdKd }
Hand 1: 53.894% 53.71%  00.18%  919710    3127.00   { TcTh }
```

Comment: so is it true that almost always the pocket pair has a slight advantage?

Comment: Not always. For example, JT has a slight advantage over 22 through 66, mostly because it has lots of ways to make a straight.  So zero-gappers perform better against underpairs that don't block their ability to make straights.

Comment: hmmm, it seems then like people are too hard on pocket jacks, it blocks straight opportunities for all the broadway over-cards

Comment: But people tend to play QQ, KK, and AA similarly pre-flop to AK, so that makes it harder to justify overplaying JJ, because you might run into a bigger pair that crushes you.  If you know your opponent has AK, then it's perhaps more defensible.